# Integer input – TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Tags: string, integer, typeerror, implicit-conversion, python-3.5

I am trying to write a function that takes two integer inputs a and b and returns a random integer on the interval [a,b]. I tried...

```
from random import randint

a = input("a = ")

b = input("b = ")

print(randint(a,b))
```

... but I got the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/malcolmjonesnz/PycharmProjects/exploratorySurgery/randomIntegerGeneraterOnA,B.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(randint(a,b))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/random.py", line 218, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

I have played around trying to "explicitly" convert the inputs to strings, but I've just worked myself into a state of confusion because I'm such a beginner.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The program works well for me. Please replace input by values you define in the program, such as a=1 and b = 5.

What version of python are you using? Maybe your print command causes some errors, since the error seems to come from this line?

Comment: Python 3.5, using PyCharm as interface. Defining values within program works for me too. I was just looking for a way to generalise the program so that it wasn't specific to one interval.